# cartodb static named map with parameters

Tags: carto

I have a named map with a variable that allow me to change the css_color value of a layer when I render it using cartodb.js.

I would like to create a static map for this named map but I can't find how pass the color parameter using the map API.

https://myusername.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/static/named/my_named_map/800/600.jpg
gives me :

```
{
  "error": "Invalid css_color value for template parameter 'color_up': "
}
```

https://myusername.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/static/named/my_named_map/800/600.jpg?config={color_up:"#f2bb00"}
gives me :

```
{
  "error": "malformed config parameter, should be a valid JSON"
}
```

I also tried ?color_up="#f2bb00" without success. Any ideas ? There is nothing in the documentation so it may not be possible to pass a parameter at all ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Maps API documentation? There is an example on setting the config with CartoCSS here: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#params-2

Comment: yes but I think it is different. There are no examples in the doc to create a static map from a named map with parameters